# Doctrine2 QueryBuilder select entity and count of associated entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I'm having a huge problem with ORM QueryBuilder. What I need to do is:
I need to fetch `order` with count of its `products` and plenty of associated entities (associated with `order`), but I assume they're not relevant here. I also need to order result by that count.

Could anyone give me an example of how this can be achieved? I would like to avoid "inline" DQLs if possible.

Comment: I think about 2 solutions. First is to keep number of products in order table then You will avoid complicated and slow query. Second is to use DQL with [DTO](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#new-operator-syntax) object

Comment: Or you count in PHP if you already fetch the products too.

Comment: @skowron-line this is not viable, because in next step I'll need to filter the "count" by status of the product and thus it will get updated really frequently. I'd like to avoid unnecessary updates to count field in order. Also it goes against normalization.

Comment: @FrankB I don't fetch them from database, only need their count. I'd like to avoid fetching 20~ products for order when I need to fetch 15~ orders.

Comment: It's possible via `Doctrine Query Builder`. You are supposed to left join `products` from `order` and then group by `order id`. You can have `COUNT(product.id)` in your select statement. Let me know if you need a code snippet.

Comment: How is the Entity Relationship between `Order` and `Product`?

Comment: It's many-to-one unidirectional ;)

Comment: @Jeet thanks, that's just great :) works as expected - I was missing the "group by" clause which caused weird results!

Comment: Glad, it helped. :)

Comment: @Jeet, maybe you should post that as an answer so the question can be closed and others don't waste their time here...

Comment: One note, it is generally a bad idea to make your Orders dependents to your Products. I advise you to create an OrderLine and copy-back Product information to it. An Order is something that happened at precise moment in time and should be stored as it.

Comment: @BorisGuéry this is great addition indeed. My Order -> Product scenario was only an example and in reality I'm dealing with a bit more complex data and scenario, just thought it would be good to isolate the issue with something easier than getting into details not relevant to that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get data via Doctrine Query Builder.

You are supposed to left join products from `Order` and then group by order id. You can have `COUNT(product.id)` in your select statement and use the alias in `order by` clause to make your orders sorted. Below is a small code snippet from `Repository`.

```
/**
 * @return \Doctrine\ORM\Query
 */
public function getHotelAndRoomType()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('order')
        ->select('partial order.{id, orderId} as order, count(product.id) as total_products_in_order')
        ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Product', 'product', 'WITH', 'product.order = order.id')
        ->groupBy('order.id')
        ->orderBy('total_products_in_order', 'DESC')
    ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
}
```

Note : Code not tested.

Comment: Works as expected, this is the right solution I was looking for.